# Navbar overlaps game UI in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 game that suddenly got an issue with WP8.1 devices that don't have hardware buttons: new navbar overlaps game, but all methods to determine screen size return correct size: 480x800, although it's obvious that it's drawn at 480x854.

I've tried putting XAML elements over the screen and they are drawn properly (not overlapped), but they don't help because their coordinates can't help me to determine if screen has a navbar.

How can a presence of a navbar be determined and how can an accurate rendering be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked for a physical aspect of the screen and added vertical scale factor depending on difference between physical and app aspects:

```
    Size screenSize = (Size)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("PhysicalScreenResolution");
    double physicalAspect = screenSize.Height / screenSize.Width;
    double appAspect = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
    double aspectDifference = appAspect / physicalAspect;
    // Set window bounds in dips
    m_d3dBackground.WindowBounds = new Windows.Foundation.Size(
        (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth,
        (float)Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight * aspectDifference
        );
```